# How to retrieve all rows using Azure Table Storage bindings for Azure Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am using azure table storage bindings as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-input?tabs=in-process%2Cstorage-extension&pivots=programming-language-javascript

I have it setup and working, but in my javascript, I reference it as such

```js
context.log(context.bindings.entity.length);
```

This outputs 50 even though the table has 745 records.

I have tried iterating it, and filtering it as such

```js
var foo = context.bindings.entity.map( (x) => x.Partition ); // only outputs 50 records
var bar = context.bindings.entity.filter( (x) => x.RowKey == "700" ); // does not find anything because the RowKey is the 700th item, and it only has 50
```

I need a way of getting all data from the azure table and filtering out what I need.

Answer (score 0):

> **Retrieve all rows using Azure Table Storage bindings**

Create ***Azure Function***  and **+** Add HTTP trigger  **->** Now click on to the **Integrate tab**  **->**  Click on the ***New Input*** and Select ***Azure Table Storage*** from the list **->** Set up ***Azure Table storage***

> **Note:** The Partition key and Row key fields are optional. Make sure to fill in the maximum number of records to read, then only it will ***read all records***.

[image: ref1]
Now go to the index.js file .Open it and replace its content with the following code.

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log(context.bindings.inputTable.FirstName);
};
```

[image: Ref2]

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table-input?tabs=in-process%2Cstorage-extension&pivots=programming-language-javascript